# Match based on column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, matching

```
| response                        | Account_Number | report_Length |
| ---------------------------     | -------------- | ------------- |
| [1670]                          |    1670        |  [91]         |
| [7910, 8329]                    |    7910        |  [90, 91]     |
|[XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3279, 4361, 1917]|    4361        |  [89, 91]     |
| [3167, 9691]                    |    NA          |  [90]         |
```

Transform above table into below table by matching with response and account_number column.

```
| response       | Account_Number | report_Length |
| ----------     | -------------- | ------------- |
| 1670           |    1670        |  91           |
| 7910           |    7910        |  90           |
| 4361           |    4361        |  89           |
| NA             |    NA          |  0            |
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Create report length column

Comment: Why do you need dataframe for this ? response[0]['report_Length']  should be enough

Comment: That was only one row. I have multiple rows in data. Response is different for different id's and can have multiple account numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You first Extract the values from `response` and `report_Length` columns with the help of `apply()` and `lambda`, after that replace `"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3279"` with the corresponding Account_Number using `df.loc` and finally you remove rows with Account_Numbers that are `"NA"`.

```py
df["response"] = df["response"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df["report_Length"] = df["report_Length"].apply(lambda x: x[0])

df.loc[df["response"] == "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3279", "response"] = df.loc[df["response"] == "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3279", "Account_Number"]
df = df[df["Account_Number"] != "NA"]

print(df)
```

---

```
  response Account_Number  report_Length
0     1670           1670             91
1     7910           7910             90
2     4361           4361             89
```

Comment: While extracting, values are not always in the first position.